# How to Implement a Hall Sensored BLDC Motor Driver using STM32?

Tags: c, keil, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, motordriver

I want to implement a BLDC Motor commutation using STM32f446RE with hall sensor interface. I want to do it with STM32Cube. I know that I should config TIM4 in Hall Sensor Mode and 3 channels of  Tim1 in PWM mode with Trigger Source of ITR3 ; but I don't know what should I do after that in the generated code. Could anyone help?

Comment: Well, I would start by polling the sensor inputs and checking that the values change when you spin the shaft.  You have to split big problems up.

Comment: Actually polling is not the best solution. I want to do it with the minimum cpu usage, using timer internal triggering.

Comment: Sure, but to get started....